# using float numbers in embedded libraries

Tags: c, embedded

When I make I2C or UART library I need to include floating point in order to put the right bits into the registers that controlthe bit-rate or baud rate in these peripherals by using a formulas like the following one that is responsible of putting the right bits into UBBR register which controls the baud rate :`

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#define BAUD_RATE 9600
#define FACTOR_8_16 16

/*calculate UBBR value */
uint16_t UBBR_value = lrint(( F_CPU / (FACTOR_8_16 * (float)BAUD_RATE) ) - 1);
//Put the upper part of the UBBR value here (bits 8 to 11)
UBRRH = (uint8)(UBBR_value >> 8);
//Put the remaining part of the UBBR value here
UBRRL = (uint8)UBBR_value;
```

The UBBR becomes 6 but when I remove the (float)type casting the UBBR becomes 5
which generates a different baud rate that's why I need to use floating point in order to get the accurate number, is this a bad approach as I should totally avoid using floating number as it adds massive blocks of code into program code,should I change it and use another way or is it ok? 
I can use some other ways but they will be more limited(because some way I can use is to limit the baud rate to certain values that are standardised ,  I won't be able to put any baud rate freely)

actually in the question I am talking generally -not just in the UART case- that if I faced I problem that the best solution to it is by including some floating point arithmetic should I avoid it and use another approach that might be not as good as the floating point approach but still gives the right answer , or is it okay to use it?

Comment: surely this is a calculation you can do without floating point, if you post the values of your macros someone may be able to help

Comment: Please provide the definitions of `F_CPU`, `FACTOR_8_16` and `BAUD_RATE`. The answer may depend on it.

Comment: Baud rates are usually allowed to be off by some percentage. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/how-critical-are-uart-frequencies

Comment: `#define F_CPU 1000000UL` suggests that floating point should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I'm getting 12 with and without float: [demonstration here](http://ideone.com/nAxZrN):

Comment: @MichaelWalz sorry I edited it, put 16 instead of 8  the value with floating point will be 6 and without it it'll be 5

Comment: You could also hardcode  it.

Comment: None of this needs to be at runtime.  Use the preprocessor to do the math.

Comment: you certainly dont need the multiply, much less floating point.  you can do the rounding as well with fixed point if you feel the need to round.  Fractional baud rate, which I assume you dont have here, fixed point no need for float, none of this math needs float to get the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need floating point here at all.

```
(FACTOR_8_16 * BAUD_RATE) = 76000

F_CPU / (FACTOR_8_16 * BAUD_RATE) ) = 
1000000 / 76000 = 13.1578   which will be rounded
                            o 13 by integer arithmetic
```

So you can just write this:

```
/*calculate UBBR value */
uint16_t UBBR_value = F_CPU / (FACTOR_8_16 * BAUD_RATE) - 1;
//Put the upper part of the UBBR value here (bits 8 to 11)
UBRRH = (uint8)(UBBR_value >> 8);
//Put the remaining part of the UBBR value here
UBRRL = (uint8)UBBR_value;
```

Comment: the example in my question the UBBR value will be 6 , but if I remove the (float) type casting) it will be 5 , and using the 9600 baud rate is very common in use , I am talking generally -not just in this case-that if I had to use floating point arithmetic  in a library should I avoid using it and look for another way or is it okay?

Comment: @AliMak I'm getting 12 with and without float: [demonstration here](http://ideone.com/nAxZrN):

Comment: @AliMak and yes, if you can avoid floating point in embedded systems whose hardware doesn't support floating point, avoid it. But it depends on each case.

Comment: these do not require floating point, in a constrained system like this you should make an effort to avoid floating point.  Floating point is nothing more than fixed point with some grade school knowledge, you can do much of the work without.  Particularly avoid it if possible if you dont have an FPU.  so when you say in general, I recommend in general dont use it.  There are exceptions sure and you have to deal with the compilation issues, code bloat and poor performance.

Comment: "which will be rounded
                            o 13 by integer arithmetic" is not quite correct.  The quotient is _truncated_ to 13.  To calculated a _round to nearest_ quotient (and with positive dividend/divisor), first add half the divisor. `dv = FACTOR_8_16 * BAUD_RATE; UBBR_value = (F_CPU + dv/2) / dv - 1;`  Baud benefits with a round to nearest value.

Answer (score 0):

I used fixed point arithmetic advice from one of the comments.. so I used one bit as precision and the rest of the of the register for the integer part- used only one bit precision because I wanted only to know if the precision part is > 0.5 so I round up to the next integer number (5.5-->6), otherwise( if precision <.5) I don't

```
    #define FP_F_CPU (F_CPU<<1)  //FP for fixed point

#define FP_FACTOR_8_16 (8<<1)
/*****enter the baud rate****/
#define BAUD_RATE 9600

#define FP_BAUD_RATE ((uint32)BAUD_RATE<<1)

#define MULTIPLY_FIXED_POINT(A , B ,scale_bits) (( (A) * (B) ) >> scale_bits)

#define DIVIDE_FIXED_POINT(A ,B ,scale_bits)( ((A) << scale_bits) / (B) )

/*calculate UBBR value */
uint16 UBBR_value = DIVIDE_FIXED_POINT( (uint32)FP_F_CPU, MULTIPLY_FIXED_POINT((uint32)FP_FACTOR_8_16, (uint32)FP_BAUD_RATE,1)  ,1 )  - (1 << 1);
if((UBBR_value & 1) ) //if the percent is 0.5
    UBBR_value = (UBBR_value >> 1) +1; //remove the extra fraction bit and round up 
else
    UBBR_value >>= 1; // else just remove the extra fraction bit
```